# FATAL: password authentication failed for user “postgres” (postgresql 12 with pgAdmin 4)

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4, postgresql-12

I recently installed Postgresql 12, during the installation, there's no step to put password and username for Postgres. Now in pgAdmin 4, I wanted to connect the database to server and it's asking me to input password, and I haven't put any in the first place. Any one knows what's going on. Thank you!

Comment: check your `pg_hba.conf` -file. You can always access your database from console with command `sudo -u postgres psql` where "postgres" is name of the user for postgres.

Comment: Also, add your operating system and which installation method you used.